# How to retrieve data where a record field matches with any item in the given list?

Tags: android, kotlin, graphql, aws-amplify

How to get all records from AWS Amplify GraphQL API where the field(example busNumber) of a model matches with any item in the given list.
Note:- busNumber is of type String

I am using AWS client side library to perform this in Kotlin in android studio.

My Dependencies are:-

```
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:core:1.4.0'
   
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-api:2.14.1'
```

This is my GraphQL Schema model which I want to retrieve

```
type DIMTSRealTimeGTFS @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  busNumber: String
  feed: Feed
}
```

Currently, What I am doing is with the following code

```
 Amplify.API.query(ModelQuery.list(DIMTSRealTimeGTFS::class.java,
      DIMTSRealTimeGTFS.BUS_NUMBER.contains("ABC").or(DIMTSRealTimeGTFS.BUS_NUMBER.contains("XYZ"))),{ reponse->
            Log.d(TAG, "queryNotes: response = "+reponse.data)
        },{
            Log.d(TAG, "queryNotes: Exception = "+it.message)
        })
```

But Here is a problem that I have to explicitly type "ABC" and "XYZ" along with .contains() and .or() functions. This is not dynamic.
I want to achieve-> Where I can send a list (say listOfBusNumbers) as argument and retrieve all records where field busNumber matches with any item in the listOfBusNumbers

Thanks in Advance.